# k-hot encoded feature Tensorflow Estimator

Tags: python, tensorflow, encoding

Let's say I have the following pandas dataframe:

```
   | col1 | col2  |     col3    |
---------------------------------
0  | 5    |  4    | [0,2,4]     |
1  | 3    |  8    | [7,3]       |
2  | 2    |  1    | [7,3,6,9]   |
```

in **'col3'** I have lists with different sizes which I also want to import into my Tensorflow Estimator. These lists also must be k-hot encoded, I am not sure if this is how people call it:

```
[1,4,6] ---> [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]
```

The problem comes because the maximum number in col3 is 600_000 so my k-hot encoded vector will have size of 600_000 thus I cannot encode my entire dataframe  (due to MemoryError) and pass **col3** to Tensorflow as

```
tf.feature_column.numeric_column('col3', 600_000)
```

Do you have any ideas how can I feed this column in my DNNRegressor ? To share some code, this is how I normally do it for 'standard' columns:

```
# reading the columns from the pandas_input_fn
col1 = tf.feature_column.numeric_column('col1', default_value=0.0)
col2 = tf.feature_column.numeric_column('col2', default_value=0.0)

# converting them to categorical
col1_b = tf.feature_column.bucketized_column(col1, [0,5,10,20])
col1_2 = tf.feature_column.bucketized_column(col2, [0,4,8,16])

# make crosses
cross = tf.feature_column.crossed_colum([col1_b, col2_b], 4*4)

# define what will go in my estimator
features = [
   tf.feature_column.embedding_column(cross, 10)
   tf.feature_column.indicator_column(col1_b)
   tf.feature_column.indicator_cilumn(col2_b)
]

# and finally
estimator = tf.estimator.DNNRegressor(
              model_dir=model_dir, 
              feature_columns=features, 
              hidden_units=[512,256,256,128,32])
```

Comment: Hi Vasil, have you figured out how to do this?

Comment: unfortunately, no

Comment: Do you have __600 000__ different values or you have something like `[1,2,5, 10, 100, 25000, 600000]`, e.g. most of the values from the range `[0, 600000]` are non-existent in your dataset?

Comment: "These lists also must be k-hot encoded" why?

Comment: hi can we split the big data into the chunks of small data ?

Comment: a very slow solution would be to encode row by row. However, my main question is: are you sure you want to create 600.000 variables? that will lead to a huge decrease in terms of degrees of freedom

Comment: Symon question is crucial, but also, what's the maximum length of the lists in col3? I think you could split those lists into new columns if it's smaller than 600 000 (columns with NA's would be generated for shorter lists than maximum) and use them after encoding the NA's.